# I want to sell/selling my products on your website

Tags: to-infinitive

> #### To-infinitive or -ing form with a change in meaning
>
> ---
>
> Some verbs can be followed by a to-infinitive or the -ing form, but with a **change in meaning**:
>
> ```
> go on    need     remember    try
> mean     regret   stop        want
> ```
>
> [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/verb-patterns-verb-infinitive-or-verb-ing)

So, what is the difference in meaning between the following:

> - I want to sell my products on your website.
> - I want selling my products on your website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Want" can be used to form a *concealed passive construction* when it means "to need something". This passive construction doesn't need a form of *BE* but it needs a form of *gerund-participle* verb. And as always, passives don't take an object, so "selling my products" isn't a correct construction. It should be

> My products want(=need) selling(=to be sold) on your website.

But as a rule, *want* takes to-infinitive when it's used to express a desire.

> I want to sell my products on your website.

Answer (score 0):

To put it simply, the first sentence means you want to sell your products on his website.  The second sentence means you don't speak English natively.

If what you want is a verb, the verb should be infinitive: "I want to ---."

A few verbs (as noted, "try" and "remember") can take the gerund, but "want" is not one of those.

Comment: Want can take a gerund but better not use one with want.